# How to replace characters on both sides of a linebreak in RStudio?

Tags: regex, rstudio

I have numerous occurrences of the following in a long RStudio script:

```
,
)
```

And I would like to find all these occurrences of a comma followed by a linebreak and a closing bracket and replace them with a single closing bracket: `)`

I can't seem to get RStudio to find both characters and the line break. I have tried: `,$)` , `,\n)` , `,[\n])`, `,\\n)` and various similar combinations. The regex box is ticked.

Comment: I'm on windows, so I assume that means ```,\n\)```? Thanks, but didn't work :(

Comment: You could copy and paste the script as a string object in R, and then run `stringr::str_remove_all(my_script_in_a_string_object, ",\\n")` and save the output as a text file to recover it.